# How to disable tap on the inner child of the InkWell?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this widget

```
InkWell(
    onTap: (){
      // clicks overAll
    },
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text('Sample one'),
        SizedBox(),
        Text('Sample two'),
        AnotherWidget(), 
        AnotherWidget2(),// want to disable click only this widget
      ],
    ),
  );
```

I want to disable the click only to the `AnotherWidget2()` widget. but Inkwell not allowing that even If I use `IgnorePointer` on the `AnotherWidget2()`
I know that I can put `InkWell` individually on every widget except `AnotherWidget2()`. But Is there any way to acheive without putting `InkWell` on individual widgets?

Comment: you want to click only `AnotherWidget2()` not other ?

Comment: I want to click everything except `AnotherWidget2()`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you. Wrap your `AnotherWidget2()` with `InkWell()` and set `onTap()=>null`

```
 InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    // clicks overAll
    print('clicks overAll');
  },
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text('Sample one'),
      SizedBox(),
      Text('Sample two'),
      Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 200,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10), 
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: ()=> null,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```